# Display child categories in the top menu in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I need to display all the subcategories in the top menu navigation in my custom module.

From the below code i m getting only the categories in the menu.

```
public function getMenu2($_cats, &$menu, $text = '', $parent = 0){ print_r($hasChild);
    $hasChild = false;
    $w1 = 50; $h1 = 50;

    //Begin-Home page hover menu 
    $_categories =  $this->getCategories();    
    $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
    $menu2 = '<ul '.($parent==0?'class="recipecatmneu row"':'').'>';
    $store_id = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    foreach($_cats as $item)
    {   
        $langtxt = $item->getLanguage();
        $langtxt = json_decode($langtxt, true);

        if($store_id && is_array($langtxt) && @$langtxt[$store_id]){
            $currentData = $langtxt[$store_id];
            foreach($currentData as $k => $v){
                if(!in_array($k, array('id' , 'filename' , 'category_id' , 'urlwrite'))) $item->setData($k, $v);
            }
        }
        //begin code change to disable categories in hover
        if($item->getParentid() == $parent && $item->getStatus()!=2){
        //end code change to disable categories in hover    
            $hasChild = true;  
            $menu .= $menu2;
            $menu2 = '';
            $menu .= '<li>
                <a class="image_gal" title="'.$item->getTitle().'" href="'.$item->getLink().'">
                    <img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $item->getFilename().'" alt="'.$item->getTitle().'" />
                </a>
                <a href="'.$item->getLink().'" title="'.$item->getTitle().'">'.$text.$item->getTitle().'</a>';
            //$this->getMenu2($_cats, $menu, $text, $item->getCategoryId());
            //End-Home page hover menu 

            $menu .= '</li>';
        }       
    }
    if($parent==0 || $hasChild){
        $menu .= '</ul>';
    }
}
```

How to get the subcategories/child categories here??

Answer (score 0):

did you click "Include in Navigation Menu" ???

magento admin > catalog > manage categories > click the category and click "Include in Navigation Menu"